# Remote Whiteboards

Tags: video

Our software development team is spread out.  We desperately need a white boarding solution and the basic web based ones aren't cutting the mustard.  We've tried using our tablets to share our drawings, but they feel too small.

The key features:

1. Two way sharing.  I can draw and the guys on the other side can too, in near real time.
2. It's big enough to be useful.  I'm used to 6' x 4' whiteboards.  Something the size of a 60 inch TV would work.
3. I can capture and save the drawings for later.

$2,000 is probably the upper limits of the budget.

Comment: In all honesty, I think $2000 is way *under* budget for something like this.

Comment: 2000 does sound a bit low but I am looking into this for you.

Comment: I've been looking at a Wacom tablet, something like this:  http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-displays/cintiq-27-qhd-touch  It's not quite a 60 inch TV, but it seems like it could meet a lot of needs.  I don't know much about these.  Ideally, it would work as a 4th monitor on my desktop.  I could maybe put a software solution on it that solves the sharing, leaving the realestate and naturalness of using a pen to the device.  Any thoughts here?